# jquery toggling elements for editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi im trying to create an edit script in jquery that changes p content to input fields, and lets people edit them and then revert back to content.

my code:

```
<div class="addressblock">
<div class="data">
<p name="bedrijfsnaam">company name</p>
<p name="tav">to whom</p>
<p name="adres">street and number</p>
<p name="postcode">1234AB</p> 
<p name="woonplaats">city</p>
<p name="land2" >Land</p>
</div>
<a href="#_" class="editinv" id="00001" name="edit">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Jquery =

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$(".editinv").click(function() {

    var editid = $(this).attr("id");
    var edit_or_text = $(this).attr("name");

    if(edit_or_text == "edit"){


    $(this).closest('div').find('p').each(function(){

    var el_naam = $(this).attr("name");
    var el_content = $(this).text();

    $(this).replaceWith( "<input type='text' name='"+el_naam+"' id='" + el_id + "' value='"+el_content+"' />" );


});
$(".editinv").replaceWith( "<a href='#_' class='editinv' name='done' id='"+editid+"'>Done</a>" );

}

if(edit_or_text == "done"){

    $(this).closest('div').find('input').each(function(){

    var el_naam = $(this).attr("name");
    var el_content = $(this).attr("value");

    $(this).replaceWith( "<p name='"+el_naam+"' id='" + el_id + "'>'"+el_content+"' </p>" );


});
$(".editinv").replaceWith( "<a href='#_' class='editinv' name='edit' id='"+editid+"'>Bewerken</a>" );

}

});
});
```

When clicking on edit it changes perfectly to input fields and changes the edit button to a done button. A click on the done button is never registered though, while the class is the same.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I created a JSfiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/hBJ5a/

ITs quite simple, why doesn't the element accept a second click and revert back after already being changed?

Comment: Changes to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SAERE/2/

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you change the name of all the `<p>` tags to the same name, and try to revert them back, there is no way that javascript will know which value should go where.

You should add an additional parameter to your `<p>` tags that will indicate the type.

e.g.

```
<p data-type="text" name="bedrijfsnaam">compname</p>
```

when changed will turn into:

```
<input type="text" name="bedrijfsnaam" data-type="edit" value="compname" />
```

when you click the button to change back, you should simply use the same function you are currently using to change the `<p>`'s into `<input>`'s, but then reverse the order.

e.g.

```
function inputToParagraph() {

    var inputs = $('input[data-type="edit"]');
    inputs.each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<p data-type="text" name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'">'+$(this).attr('value')+'</p>');
    });
}
```

ofcourse you should have other actions linked to your submit, an ajax request probably to update the database as well.

**NOTE**
Not tested, but do know that the function above, if all the attr's are specified will work.
It will directly replace the inputs with P tags with given attributes.

You will have to make sure when you make the `<p>`'s into `<input>`'s, you will have to make sure the inputs get the correct attributes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var clickHandler = function() {
            var editid = $(this).attr("id");
            var edit_or_text = $(this).attr("name");
            if (edit_or_text == "edit") {
                $(this).closest('div').find('p').each(function() {
                    var el_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var el_naam = el_id; //$(this).attr("name");
                    var el_content = $(this).text();
                    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='text' name='" + el_naam + "' id='" + el_id + "' value='" + el_content + "' />");
                });
                $(".editinv").replaceWith("<a href='#_' class='editinv' name='done' id='" + editid + "'>Done</a>");
            }
            else /* if (edit_or_text == "done") */ {
                $(this).closest('div').find('input').each(function() {
                    var el_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    //var el_naam = el_$(this).attr("name");
                    var el_content = document.getElementById(el_id).value;
                    // Attribute "name" not allowed on element "p" at this point
                    //$(this).replaceWith("<p name='" + el_naam + "' id='" + el_id + "'>'" + el_content + "' </p>");
                    $(this).replaceWith("<p id='" + el_id + "'>" + el_content + "</p>");
                });
                $(".editinv").replaceWith("<a href='#_' class='editinv' name='edit' id='" + editid + "'>Bewerken</a>");
            }
            document.getElementById("00001").onclick = clickHandler;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("00001").onclick = clickHandler;
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="addressblock">
        <div class="data">
            <!-- Attribute "name" not allowed on element "p" at this point -->
            <p id="bedrijfsnaam">company name</p>
            <p id="tav">to whom</p>
            <p id="adres">street and number</p>
            <p id="postcode">1234AB</p> 
            <p id="woonplaats">city</p>
            <p id="land2">Land</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#_" class="editinv" id="00001" name="edit">Edit</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested with Firefox 24.0 / Linux

Comment: Ok thanks, but why do you change el_naam to el_id? The id is for the entire adress entry, the names are for the individual parts. Like this I cant know what field is what when posting right?

Comment: The "name" attribute is not standard conform as used, please see the comment "Attribute 'name' not allowed on element 'p' at this point", it is taken from the syntax check of my NetBeans IDE. In the "input" tag the "name" attribute is acceptable. If you want to realize more than one "addressblock" you may, for example, combine the id like "bedrijfsnaam" with the id of the "a" tag like "bedrijfsnaam00001". If my answer helped you i will be happy about an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

try out jquery editable plugin

demo: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html